# Laravel Administrator Localization

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications, web

I'm working with Laravel 5.3 and I am unable to use some of the public packages which are offering localization messages in the database. I have an order to create a website for a hotel. They want 3 different languages to display their information and I'm not really sure how to create the admin panel so the administrator could enter information in 3 different languages.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Translation of content is different than UI and that is different from translation of UI that is user-defined; its hard topic and you better plan ahead. Unfortunately SO is mostly aimed for programming problems that include code samples (I know there is plenty of Q&A with no code involved but thats old-school), your question is going to get closed sooner or later because its broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you would need a table, with relation to all other tables ([Polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)), to hold the translation strings.

so i suggest you start with [Voyager](https://voyager.readme.io/docs), it's a dashboard with the localization built-in,